# Discord.js(v13) DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message when trying to do a word filter bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Curently, I'm trying to do a bot that would filter bad words, and delete the message that contains the bad word.

When I launch my bot, and type a word I defined, my bot delete the message and reply but :

- It replies 2 times (or more sometimes),
- Everytime the bot sends the message, I got following error:

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
```

Here is my code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
if(message.author.bot) return;

    let words = ["word1", "word2"];

    let foundInText = false;

    for (let i in words) {
        if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(words[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(`${message.author}, your message has been deleted for swearing!`);
    }
```

Thanks by advance for your help !

Comment: Did you give your bot the message content intent?

Comment: Yes, my bot has this permission, and this one is also enabled on Discord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible that the code is trying to delete a message that doesn't exist? I'd check if the message exists before deleting.

here's improved code to check that:

````
  if (message.author.bot) return;
 
  const prohibitedWords = ["word1", "word2"];
 
  let foundProhibitedWord = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < prohibitedWords.length; i++) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(prohibitedWords[i].toLowerCase())) {
      foundProhibitedWord = true;
      break;
    }
  }
 
  if (foundProhibitedWord) {
    try {
      const deletedMessage = await message.delete();
      message.channel.send(`${message.author}, your message has been deleted for swearing!`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error deleting message: ${error}`);
    }
  }
});```

explanation before using:
The error DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message occurs when a message is deleted and an attempt is made to perform an action on the message thereafter. To avoid this error, the revised code that I provided earlier adds a check for whether the message exists before attempting to delete it.

The new code creates a try...catch block that catches any errors occurring during the deletion process, particularly the DiscordAPIError error. If the error is a DiscordAPIError error with an HTTP status code of 404, which means "Not Found", the code logs a message to the console indicating that the message could not be found. If it is not a 404 error, the error is logged to the console for further investigation.

The revised code also uses async/await for the deletion of messages, which allows the messages to be deleted asynchronously and the error to be caught appropriately.
````

Comment: Thanks! I tried with your code and it works now! Many thanks for your help! :D